# "Select/Unselect" event for mat-tab-group

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

In this mat-tab-group, I find out "Select Unselect" event for same tab. When I select the tab the tab is fully selected and the page is properly routing but when I go to sub-route on this same page then the page changes but the tab remains selected.

At that time I want the tab to be unselected or the event is deleted.

Comment: please share minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!